# Enhance image quality by white and black clearer

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to improve the quality of an image using python. How can I get white and black more clearer so as to enhance the quality of the image
Here's my try

```
from PIL import Image

def enhance_image(img):
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    threshold = (138, 138, 138)
    img = Image.open(img).convert("LA")
    pixels = img.getdata()
    newPixels = []
    
    for pixel in pixels:
        if pixel < threshold:
            newPixels.append(black)
        else:
            newPixels.append(white)

    newImg = Image.new("RGB",img.size)
    newImg.putdata(newPixels)
    newImg.save("MyTemp.jpg")
```

Here's a sample image
[image]

Comment: maybe better use `OpenCV` for this. It can be more useful

Comment: See Google Tesseract OCR documentation: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality) - it describe how to create better image for detecting text. There is even link to `OpenCV` which has function to do some desribed modifications.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just need a way to focus on black and white pixels

Comment: OpenCV read image as `numpy.array` so it can do change pixels in one line `img[ img < threshold ] = white` - and it can do it faster. It have also special functions for `threshold`. It has also function for `dilation` to make text little bolder.

Comment: [Python | Thresholding techniques using OpenCV | Set-1 (Simple Thresholding) - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-thresholding-techniques-using-opencv-set-1-simple-thresholding/?ref=lbp)

Comment: [Erosion and Dilation of images using OpenCV in python - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/erosion-dilation-images-using-opencv-python/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried `ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` and `ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)` and both are perfect but I need more contrast if possible. How can I improve it?

Comment: maybe ask on [forum OpenCV](https://forum.opencv.org/) or search in blog [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/blog/)